# How to add common methods for a few Java enums? (abstract class ancestor?)

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, enums

I have a few Java enums as such

```
public enum Aggregation
{
    MORTGAGE( "Mortgage" ),
    POOLS( "Pools" ),
    PORTFOLIO( "Portfolio" );

    private Aggregation( final String name )
    {
        m_Name = name;
    }
    private String m_Name;
    static Map< String, Aggregation > c_LOOKUP =
        new HashMap< String, Aggregation >();
    static {
        for (Aggregation agg:values()){
            c_LOOKUP.put(agg.m_Name,agg);
        }
    }

    public Aggregation lookup(String name){
        return c_LOOKUP.get( name );
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return m_Name;
    }
}

public enum Interval
{
    MONTHLY( "Monthly" ),
    QUARTLY( "Quartly" ),
    SEMIANNUALLY( "SemiAnnually" ),
    ANNUALLY("Annually");

    private Interval( final String name )
    {
        m_Name = name;
    }
    private String m_Name;
    static Map< String, Interval > c_LOOKUP =
        new HashMap< String, Interval >();
    static {
        for (Interval agg:values()){
            c_LOOKUP.put(agg.m_Name,agg);
        }
    }

    public Interval lookup(String name){
        return c_LOOKUP.get( name );
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return m_Name;
    }
}
```

As you can see, there are quite some code duplication here.  It would be nice if there is a way to introduce something like an abstract common ancestor class. But java enum cannot inherent. What would be the best approach?  Thanks.

---

Edit:
I have work out a version similar to ŁukaszBachman and missingfacktor

```
static public enum Aggregation
{
    MORTGAGE( "Mortgage" ),
    POOLS( "Pools" ),
    PORTFOLIO( "Portfolio" );

    private final String m_Name;

    final static private ReverseDictionary< Aggregation > c_DICTIONARY =
        new  ReverseDictionary< Aggregation >( Aggregation.class );

    static public Aggregation lookup( final String name )
    {
        return c_DICTIONARY.lookup( name );
    }

    private Aggregation( final String name )
    {
        m_Name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return m_Name;
    }
}

static public enum Interval
{
    MONTHLY( "Monthly" ),
    QUARTLY( "Quartly" ),
    SEMIANNUALLY( "SemiAnnually" ),
    ANNUALLY( "Annually" );

    private final String m_Name;
    final static private ReverseDictionary< Interval > c_DICTIONARY =
        new ReverseDictionary< Interval >( Interval.class );

    static public Interval lookup( final String name )
    {
        return c_DICTIONARY.lookup( name );
    }

    private Interval( final String name )
    {
        m_Name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return m_Name;
    }
}


static public class ReverseDictionary< E extends Enum< E >>
{
    Map< String, E > c_LOOKUP = new HashMap< String, E >();

    public ReverseDictionary( final Class< E > enumClass )
    {
        for( final E agg : EnumSet.allOf( enumClass ) )
        {
            c_LOOKUP.put( agg.toString(), agg );
        }
    }

    public E lookup( final String name )
    {
        return c_LOOKUP.get( name );
    }

}
```

I see some reasoning.  However, it is still not very satisfactory.

1. It is hard to define the interface for `lookup(String)` because of the different return type
2. I can appreciate that the `lookup(String)` is not really duplication but a specification, but I am still feel that m_Name field and the toString() logic is a bit redundant.  We are really specifying one category of enum, and it seems to be **"is-a"** relationship in my opinion.

Comment: If inheritance does not work, delegation will do the trick.

Comment: You can't inherit static stuff anyway, so even if enums supported implementation inheritance, that would not help.

Comment: buc, Could you please be a little more specific? Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using [valueOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) instead of all that lookup stuff? It seems to be most of the duplicated code, and you get it for free in any enum anyway.

Comment: `valueOf` will not recognize `m_Name`.

Comment: So you have all this logic just to have the values names all uppercase, while their content with only one capital letter? I'd probably change the naming of the values to match their required content, and thus eliminate all that logic. I know you're asking a general question, so this is merely a comment. It's just one of those cases when formal practices (naming conventions here) introduce otherwise unnecessary logic. Giving up formality can yield better code, without having to use some fancy pattern.

Comment: To address 1: `lookup`, if you make it a class method, would have to be static, and static fields/methods cannot be left abstract or be overridden.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Favor **composition over inheritance** and **programming for the sake of interfaces**. Since Enums are classes (not regular, but still - classes) you can create some field containing shared logic, let the enum implement you interface and delegate implementation to this field.

Relevant code snippets:

**Shared interface**

```
public interface MyInterface {

    void someMethod();

}
```

**Logic implementation**

```
public class MyInterfaceImpl implements MyInterface {

    public void someMethod() {
        System.out.println("Do smth...");
    }

}
```

**First enum**

```
public enum EnumA implements MyInterface {
    ;

    private MyInterface impl = new MyInterfaceImpl();

    public void someMethod() {
        impl.someMethod();
    }

}
```

**Second enum**

```
public enum EnumB implements MyInterface {
    ;

    private MyInterface impl = new MyInterfaceImpl();

    public void someMethod() {
        impl.someMethod();
    }

}
```

Please do note that `EnumA` and `EnumB` are not really code duplication, since that is plain delegation (valid, in my opinion). Also please note that everything is nicely glued together by using interface.

Comment: This is a nice solution. You could also let the enums *return* a `MyInterface`, and instead implement a `MyInterfaceProvider` with a `getMyInterface` method. In that way you would get rid of the duplication of the delegating methods also. This could also be combined with [Jeremy's solution that uses default methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11163968/how-to-add-common-methods-for-a-few-java-enums-abstract-class-ancestor#29792017).

Answer (score 7):

Here is how you can solve your problem with composition and delegation. (I think this is the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)est you can get with Java, for the case in hand.)

```
import java.util.*;

interface HasName {
  public String getName();
}

class EnumEnhancer<E extends Enum<E> & HasName> {
  private Map<String, E> lookup;

  public EnumEnhancer(E... values) {
    lookup = new HashMap<String, E>();
    for (E e : values) {
      lookup.put(e.getName(), e);
    }
  }

  public E lookup(String name) {
    return lookup.get(name);
  }

  public String toString(E e) {
    return e.getName();
  }
}

enum Color implements HasName { // This is interface inheritance.
  RED("red"), GREEN("green"), BLUE("blue");

  // This is composition. 
  private static final EnumEnhancer<Color> enhancer = 
    new EnumEnhancer<Color>(values());

  private String name;

  private Color(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  // This is delegation.
  public String toString() {
    return enhancer.toString(this);
  }

  // This too is delegation.     
  public static Color lookup(String name) {
    return enhancer.lookup(name);
  }
}

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Color.lookup("blue")); // prints blue
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you I mixed both solutions and I just have to call this code il my static method to create enum from internal attribute : `return new EnumEnhancer<>(values()).fromKey(key);`

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve this with Java 8 default interface methods:

```
public class test
{
    public static void main (String[] arguments) throws Exception
    {
        X.A.foo ();
        Y.B.foo ();
    }
}

interface MyEnumInterface
{
    String getCommonMessage ();
    String name ();

    default void foo ()
    {
        System.out.println (getCommonMessage () + ", named " + name ());
    }
}

enum X implements MyEnumInterface
{
    A, B;

    @Override
    public String getCommonMessage ()
    {
        return "I'm an X";
    }
}

enum Y implements MyEnumInterface
{
    A, B;

    @Override
    public String getCommonMessage ()
    {
        return "I'm an Y";
    }
}
```

Note that the interface doesn't know it will be implemented by enums, so it cannot use `Enum` methods on `this` in the default methods. However, you may include those methods in the interface itself (like I did with `name()`) and then use them normally. They will be "implemented" for you by `Enum` when you declare an enumeration.

Comment: Nice to see that java developed into some solution of an old problem.

Answer (score 0):

How about a static helper class that holds your common functions, call them from your enum methods.

In regards to your comment about toString().

```
public enum MyEnum{

ONE("one");

public MyEnum(String m_Name){
  this.m_Name = m_Name;
}
public String toString(){
  return m_Name;
}
String m_Name;
}
```

Comment: It is probably OK with the `lookup(String)` method.  But what would you do with `m_name` field and the `toString()`?

Comment: In regards to the toString() method, why not make that a instance method of the ENUM itself, rather then part of each individual ENUM you define.

Comment: I don't think extend ENUM class can work with the built-in enum type

Answer (score -1):

just define your common behviur in the First class:

```
public class First {
 public String name() {
  return "my name";
 }
 ...
}
```

and than extend it in each class:

```
public SecondClass extends First {
 ...
}
```

Comment: I don't believe it is possible for an enum to extend a class -- they can only implement interfaces.