# How to call the method of a enum which is a attribute of another enum

Tags: java, enums

I have three enums one is First, Second and Third and i want to call the method whose enum is the attribute of First enum.

```
enum First{
ACRE1("a","b","Second");
ACRE2("a","b","Third");

private final String name;
private final String secondName;
private final String thirdName;

private First(final thatName, final thatSecondName, final thatThirdName){
    this.name = thatName;
    this.name = thatSecondName;
    this.name = thatThirdName;
}

public String getThirdField(){
    return this.thirdName;
}
}

enum Second{
ABC("abc"),
CDE("cde");

private final String name;

private Second(final String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return name;
}

public static List<String> getAllHeaders() {
    List<String> allHeadersList = Stream.of(Second.values())
                                 .map(Second::toString)
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return allHeadersList;
}
}

enum Third{
ABCD("abcd"),
CDEF("cdef");

private final String name;

private Second(final String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return name;
}

public static List<String> getAllHeaders() {
    List<String> allHeadersList = Stream.of(Second.values())
                                 .map(Second::toString)
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return allHeadersList;
}
}
```

what i want is :
    first.getThirdField().getAllHeaders
Here first can be ACRE1 or ACRE2 depending upon the user input but first.getThirdField() will return a string how how to call that enum from that string?

Comment: This doesn't really make any sense. Furthermore, getAllHeaders is a static method, you can't call it as if it was an instance method. Not only that, it's not a method of a string either..

Comment: What you eventually are trying to do ist smth. like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11163968/how-to-add-common-methods-for-a-few-java-enums-abstract-class-ancestor

Comment: `Second.valueOf(First.ACRE.getThirdField()).getAllHeaders()` is a valid approach, BUT then you have to change the value of the `thirdName` in `First` to `ABC`. If you want `First` to specify the ENUM-name, then you need reflection I'd say

Comment: Instead of passing in a string to First, you could pass the Third enum directly.

Comment: @Sebastian we can't directly pass the enum as attribute as this will expect a expression.